# How to use Like condition to get specific data from dataset to datarow?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, dataset, datarow

I am using VB.Net language in .Net MVC 4.0

I am having a dataset with records like

```
1 David   05/31/2011 05/16/2011

2 Rassell 06/15/2011 06/01/2011 

3 David   06/15/2011 06/01/2011
```

like vise thousands of records are there in dataset and I just want to get  data of David using like condition from dataset to datarow.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code you can use to filter data from data-set.
Replace variable / table / column name as per your data table.

You will get an array of data-row. If you are expecting one row then take the first row from the result, else it will give you all rows having "David" as person name.

```
Dim table As DataTable = DataSet1.Tables("Orders")

Dim expression As String
expression = "PersonName Like '%David%'" 

Dim foundRows() As DataRow
foundRows = table.Select(expression)
```

Comment: I only want to use "like" expression not "=".

Comment: You can use Like operator same way as sql.

expression = "PersonName Like '%David%'"